# pip Install throwing No matching distribution found for

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I am on my work PC (corporate proxy) and i am unable to install anything using pip install.

I have tried the following:

```py
pip install QuantLib-Python
```

```py
pip install --proxy 'webproxy.abc.123.nsroot.net:8080' QuantLib-Python
```

```py
pip install --proxy "user:pass@webproxy.abc.123.nsroot.net:8080" QuantLib-
Python
```

no matter the library i always receive this message. I am on Python 3.7.3

```
Collecting QuantLib-Python
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000002BEAFD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/quantlib-python/
  Retrying 
No matching distribution found for QuantLib-Python
```

On my Home PC i ran the command pip install QuantLib-Python with the version of python and it worked perfectly.

please help!

Comment: per the [docs](https://www.quantlib.org/install/windows-python.shtml) it says if a matching distro is not found, you'll need to compile from source

Comment: thank you, but i do not believe that is the issue. everything is identical on my home PC and it works correctly. I believe this might be a proxy issue as it happens with all pip install commands.

Comment: @Jordan9588 Not everything is identical: network configuration is different. You have problems at the network or proxy level. Ask your system/network admins to help.